# Using POST variable for Postgresql with PHP

Tags: php, string, postgresql, post

I need to pass a function parameter that I get from POST to an sql query.
My connection and sql is fine because this works:

```
function getCertFromServer($username, $pwd) {
    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=company user=apache password=password");
    $result =pg_query_params($db,"select firstname, lastname from users where username=$1",array('pablo'));
...
}
```

But replacing the string by the post variable does not work.

```
$result =pg_query_params($db,"select firstname, lastname from users where username=$1",array($username));
```

I noticed this error in PSQL, so I think the solution has to be related to how I handle the string variable or quotes.

```
company=# select firstname, lastname from users where username=pablo;
ERROR:  column "pablo" does not exist
LINE 1: select firstname, lastname from users where username=pablo;
```

So I tried a bunch of different variations to try to solve it, like this:

```
$username = (string)$username;
$result =pg_query($db,"select firstname, lastname from users where username='${username}'");
```

But none worked.

edit: the POST function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var ajaxurl = 'createcer.php',
        data =  {'username': clickBtnValue, 'pwd' :pwd};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data,function (response) {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response;
        });
    });

});
```

createcer.ph:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        getCertFromServer($_POST['username'],$_POST['pwd']);
}
```

Comment: Does this work?
`$result =pg_query_params($db,"select firstname, lastname from users where username='{$username}'");`

Comment: You obviously have problem somewhere else in the code if hardcoding username into params array works. Show us the road from `$_POST['username']` to `getCertFromServer($username, $pwd)`

Comment: No it doesn't, but thank you. I think there's something wrong with how I send the string through POST.     $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var pwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var ajaxurl = 'createcer.php',
        data =  {'username': clickBtnValue, 'pwd' :pwd};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data,function (response) {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response;
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

```
var clickBtnValue = '<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>';
```

I feel like there's potential for tampering by the user though.